# AWS SDK: Request spot instance with public IP and security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am writing a script to automate the spot instances request. I am trying to achieve the same I would usually get via the console. More precisely, the instance usually has the following features:

- it belongs to a non default VPC
- it belongs to a specific security group
- it has a public IP address

I am using ruby + [the AWS SDK **EC2 Client**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html) to achieve the purpose. At the moment, the options I use are:

```
options = {
          :spot_price => "0.6", 
          :instance_count => 1,
          :type => "one-time", 
          :launch_specification => {
              :key_name => "wathever",
              :image_id => "ami-wathever",
              :instance_type => "cx.xwathever",
              :network_interfaces => [
                  {
                      :device_index => 0,
                      :delete_on_termination => true,
                      :subnet_id => "subnet-wathever",
                      :associate_public_ip_address => true
                  }
              ],
              :security_group_ids => ["sg-wathever"],
          }
      }
```

The only problem with this approach is that I get this error after issuing the request

> Network interfaces and an instance-level security groups may not be
>   specified on the same request

I am a bit lost now, because from the console it works differently. In 1 request I can specify both security group and public IP to the instance. Via the AWS SDK though it seems to not be possible.

Is it an issue with the AWS tools alignment or am I simply doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Network interfaces and an **instance-level** security groups may not be specified on the same request

What the "instance-level" bit is hinting at here is that, if you're explicitly configuring network interfaces, you need to configure the security groups that will be applied *per network interface* (using the [`groups`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Types/InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification.html#groups-instance_method) setting on the individual network interface specification). The top-level `security_group_ids` setting only works if you accept the default network interface configuration.

Comment: That was the solution. Thanks